LMS - SCORM Files
I have developed a LMS site and i have intergrated the scorm courses to it.
The scorm course are saved and rendered from s3 bucket using pre signed url.
In my LMS site i have created the SCORM api objects in a .js file and hosted on a server.
I am facing the the issue of Scorm api objects not being called when the course is rendered from s3 bucket

As you can see i have the js file as "OutermostLMSV5.js" wherein my acorm api calls are written.
And the scorm file is being viewed from s3 bucket. in this case the interactions does not happen. How to make this working?
Pls advise
